# How do I change the pin color of an annotation in map kit view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, mapkit

I would like to know how to change the pin color of an annotation in map kit. Currently Im using the following code.

```
    //King Solomon's Lodge No. 194
CLLocationCoordinate2D kingsolomons;
kingsolomons.latitude = 38.052041;
kingsolomons.longitude = -78.683218;
Annotation *kingsolomonslodge = [[Annotation alloc] init];
kingsolomonslodge.coordinate = kingsolomons;
kingsolomonslodge.title = @"King Solomon's Lodge No. 194";
kingsolomonslodge.subtitle = @"Charlottesville, VA";
[self.myMapView addAnnotation:kingsolomonslodge];
```

I have googled this question a few times but Im unsure on how to implement this into the current code that I have.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


   if (annotation == mapview.userLocation)
    return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [mapview dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"asdf"];

   if (pin == nil)
      pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier: @"asdf"] autorelease];
   else
      pin.annotation = annotation;

 //  NSLog(@"%@",annotation.title);

    NSString *titlename=@"xyz";
   if ([annotation.title isEqualToString:titlename]) {
       pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
     // pin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest.png"] ;
}
else{
    pin.pinColor= MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
}

    pin.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIButton *disclosureButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//  //pin.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrest.png"] ;



pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = disclosureButton;
//pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
pin.animatesDrop = YES;
[pin setEnabled:YES];
[pin setCanShowCallout:YES];
return pin;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pinColor property if `MKAnnotation` class.

```
kingsolomonslodge.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
```

Another way is you can use image instead of the default pin using `viewForAnnotation:` delegate:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[yourAnnotationLocation class]])
    {

        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
            annotationView.enabled = YES;
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];//here we use a nice image instead of the default pins
            annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        }
        else
        {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return annotationView;
    }

return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Midhun MP! I will look into the custom image pin as well.

Comment: @Apps: with pleasure dude :)

Comment: kingsolomonslodge.pinColor = AnnotationColorGreen; is giving me an error. Its asking me to replace it with MKPinAnnotationColorGreen; however that does not work either.. Ill play around with it.. just got home from work.

Comment: Note that with iOS 9, `annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen ` has been deprecated in favor of `annotationView.pinTintColor = [MKPinAnnotationView greenPinColor]`

Answer (score 1):

try this man...

```
kingsolomonslodge.pinColor = AnnotationColorRed;
```

let me know whether it is workihg or not

happy coding!!!!

Comment: Hello Nirav, thanks for your time.  
    kingsolomonslodge.pinColor = AnnotationColorRed; Its giving me an error and asking if I want to change it to  kingsolomonslodge.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;. However when I change it.. its saying its property pin color not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply custom color you can add image also.

```
 MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinks.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 9:

```
kingsolomonslodge.pinTintColor = UIColor.greenColor;
```